# Setting UTC timezone with numeric values in PHP

Tags: php, timezone

I receive a number (e.g. +3, +8.30, -1...) representing the UTC time zone.
I would like to set the default time zone for PHP using the UTC value, and NOT a random city name.

I know, I could create a (big) lookup array table and/or type a list of cities, but I would rather use the direct UTC offset, so my dream would be to have it working like this:

`date_default_timezone_set('UTC+3');`
or
`date_default_timezone_set('+3');`

Basically, almost like in **MySQL**:
`SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+3:00';`

I sincerely would have expected the PHP function to FIRST support numbers, and MAYBE later the city, but it looks like PHP already accepts a city name and NOT the UTC number - which should be easier to implement IMHO.

I couldn't find a way to do it without writing a lookup table, which is both ugly and slow :(

Thanks for your help

Comment: You're assuming that it's a simple lookup from name to a number.  It is not.  Please read "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the interesting link. I was (wrongly again) assuming that the DST was handled by the "server" according to the date/time, so that you set the UTC first, and then it will be the server task to add/subtract the DST if needed. Yet another reason to drop DST, it's totally useless nowadays :)

Answer (score 0):

List time zone and offset in hours

```
$time_zones =  DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers();
foreach ($time_zones as $time_zone) {
    $date = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone($time_zone));
    $offset_in_hours = $date->getOffset() / 3600;
    echo $time_zone.': ('.$offset_in_hours.') <br >';
}
```

You may try this

```
/* Takes a GMT offset (in hours) and returns a timezone name */
function tz_offset_to_name($offset) {

  $time_zones =  DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers();

  foreach ($time_zones as $time_zone) {

      $date = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone($time_zone));
      $offset_in_hours = $date->getOffset() / 3600;

      if ($offset_in_hours == $offset)
      {
        return $time_zone;
      }
  }

}
```

Set default time zone

```
$tz_offset_name = tz_offset_to_name(0);
echo $tz_offset_name;// debug purpose echoing Africa/Abidjan
date_default_timezone_set($tz_offset_name);// set new time zone with name returns
```

Get new default time zone "setted"

```
echo date_default_timezone_get();// echoing Africa/Abidjan
```

You're new default time zone is set.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know the timezone_abbreviations_list() function. Unfortunately if I call  tz_offset_to_name('0') I get Africa/Abidjan, and with tz_offset_to_name('1') I get Europe/London, so it seems somehow shifted

Comment: Welcome. It is rather logical that the function returns a different value if the parameter is different. (eg. 0 and 1). I updated my answer.

Comment: What I meant is that zero should be London, and one should be Rome/Berlin for example. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets

Comment: You're right. I updated my answer according to fix this problem.

Comment: Is it ok for you @ZioBit?

Comment: Thank you again. According to the link in the question comment, right now I am not sure it's so easy :( I am afraid that using "now" will take the DST into consideration, making the choice wrong :( I feel I opened a nest of wasps and/or the pandora box :) But thank you for pointing me at the abbreviations_list function

Comment: The error in the code shown here is assuming that the offset for "now" is the *only* offset for the time zone.  Indeed, if you run the first example at different times of the year, you will get very different lists.